# BeautifulSoup get text between elements

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have something like this:

```html
<b>foo:</b> bar

<br />


<b>baz:</b>
<font color="green">YES</font> spam

<br />


<b>eggs:</b> ham

<br />
```

Now I want to get all of those strings between `<br>`s.

I can do something like this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# get the html here
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
for element in soup.find_all('b'):
    print(element.next_sibling)
```

And it works, but only for the text not encapsulated i.e in `<font>` tags. So I would get `bar` and `ham` but I wouldn't get `YES` and unexpectedly for me I wouldn't even get `spam`. Is there a way to parse this without using regular expressions?

Comment: BeautifulSoup4 has a built in function to specifically get the text between tags. It's called `get_text()`. Find more here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text

Comment: But how does that help me exactly? It looks like it does precisely the same as `.text`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(Web scraping) I've located the proper tags, now how do I extract the text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58196341/web-scraping-ive-located-the-proper-tags-now-how-do-i-extract-the-text)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, I know how to get text between tags, like `<b>` tags, but the text here is between `<br>`s

Answer (score 2):

You can use find_all() and check all tag and then find tag based on that.
Use `next_element` to get the value.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''<b>foo:</b> bar

<br />


<b>baz:</b>
<font color="green">YES</font> spam

<br />


<b>eggs:</b> ham

<br />'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
for item in soup.find_all():
    if item.name=='font':
       print(item.text.strip())
       print(item.next_element.next_element.strip())
    if item.name=='b':
       if item.next_element.next_element.strip()!='':
           print(item.next_element.next_element.strip())
```

**Output**:

```
bar
YES
spam
ham
```

Answer (score 1):

I gave it a try. Hope it works

```
# get the html here
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
all_b=soup.find_all('b')
for b in all_b:
    print(b.get_text())
    next_b=b.findNext('b')
    #print(next_b)
    for sibling in b.next_siblings:
        if(sibling!=next_b):
            if(sibling!=None and isinstance(sibling,str)==False):
                print(sibling.get_text())
                sibling=sibling.next_sibling
            elif(sibling!=None and isinstance(sibling,str)==True):
                print(sibling)
                sibling=sibling.next_sibling
        elif(sibling==next_b):
            break
    print("new")
```

[image]

Comment: Well, it sort of works, but then if if I also want to print the text between `<b></b>`, i get: `foo: bar` `baz: ` `baz: YES`, so it gets repeated + the `<script>` part at the bottom of the page also gets parsed

Comment: @dabljues I think for that you will have to go for a recursive approach that expands nested tags.